# Can a Journey Builder Trigger compare one attribute to another attribute?

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Let's say my subscribers have two attributes, `Attribute_A` and `Attribute_B`

I want to create a Trigger expression in Journey Builder that checks if
`Attribute_A` is `Equal To` `Attribute_B`

Is it possible to build a Trigger than can do this type of comparison?

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible when using expression builder in the Journey Builder UI.

However, if you wanted to create a Custom Trigger, you would be able to pull that off.

Here is some documentation around getting started with our Platform Triggers:

[Creating Platform Triggers](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/platform/creating-platform-triggers.html)

Basically, what you'll be doing is running your own application with a Custom Trigger defined, and Journey Builder will iFrame it in during configuration time, allowing you to specify exactly what filtering you need.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation was updated a few weeks ago with what seems to be the answer to your question:

> ## [Attribute to Attribute Comparison](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/attribute_to_attribute_comparison/)
>
> Marketers use filters to make sure the intended contacts enter their journeys, follow the intended branch after a decision split, or reach the journey's goal. Many journeys use a simple filter to admit any contact with the specified value in a data field on its contact record. In some cases, marketers need the ability to compare the value in one data field against the value in another data field for a single contact to determine whether to admit that contact. Use attribute to attribute comparison to achieve this.

Problem is that it is not clear how to use it or if the feature must be enabled by the help desk first.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but answering would help the community.

With the recent changes, we can compare attributes in Journey (decision split). 

Remember to check 'Add an attribute to compare' checkbox, which will allow you to drag and drop the attribute from the library.

[image]